# d3 SVG Transitions Not Always Ending At Required Value

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I have a d3 visualisation on a web page that shows a collection of plot points on a chart.

It's all very simple really with just two axis and sometimes maybe 30 points to plot.  As I render these plots I perform a transition on the `r` attributes of the SVG circles.  The code that does this is:

```
    g.append("svg:circle")
        .attr("class", "plot-circle")
        .attr("cx", xCo)
        .attr("cy", yCo)
        .attr("r", 0)
        .transition()
        .delay(function() { return delayInput * 100; })
        .duration(plotExplosionDuration)
        .ease(Math.sqrt)
        .attr("r", 6);
```

All that occurs is that the circles are initially set to `r=0` which means they aren't rendered at all.  Then I start a transition on the appended circle to take this radius up to 6.

The problem is that it appears on some machines these transitions don't stop at `r=6` and some plots end up being much bigger than the value set after the transition.

I simply cannot duplicate this on my main development machine (PC), my iPad nor my MacBook Pro which leads me to think it might be performance or machine load causing this?

has anyone got any ideas on how to ensure the transition stops at the defined final `r` value?

Comment: If it doesn't work properly that should be a bug. It could be related to the load on the client machine.

Comment: Since I've seen it working without issue on every machine I've used it on (vary specifications as well) I'm fairly confident this is an edge case but would like to take care of it nonetheless.

Comment: So if you haven't seen the problem yourself, where and when does it occur?

Comment: One of my testers sees it on his Asus touch-screen Ultrabook.  The plots are really simple co-ordinate type objects so it's not pushing lots of JSON around in memory.  Seems to occur on a redraw when the this user selects a wider date range of data but even then it'll probably be much less than 100 plots.